# Allow staff user to only read the data

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to allow the staff users to view (read only)the transaction data. But when I login as a staff user, it displays 'You don't have permission to edit anything.' and rest of the page is blank.

models.py

```
 #models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User




from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

# Create your models here.
alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z-]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters and "-" are allowed.')

TransactionTypes = (
    ('P','Purchase'),
    ('S','Sell'),
    )
class Transactions(models.Model):
    client_name = models.OneToOneField(User(is_staff=True))
    transaction_type = models.CharField(choices=TransactionTypes,max_length=1)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, validators=[alphanumeric])
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('read_item','Can read item'),
        )
```

Admin.py-

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Transactions
# Register your models here.


class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #list_display = ('client_name', 'transaction_type', 'amount', 'transaction_id')
    list_display = ('client_name', 'transaction_type', 'amount', 'transaction_id')
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser and request.user.has_perm('transactionss.read_item'):
            return [f.name for f in self.model._meta.fields]        
        return super(TransactionAdmin, self).get_readonly_fields(
            request, obj=obj
        )

admin.site.register(Transactions, TransactionAdmin)
```